# Read number of lines in text file by XSLT code

Tags: xslt, c#-4.0

Can anyone tell me how can i read number of lines in my text files by using xslt code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you read the text file within your C# program and pass this text as a parameter to the XSLT transformation, then an XSLT **1.0** transformation **can** calculate the number of lines. Do let me know if you are interested in such a solution and I'll provide it.

Comment: thanks sir, rather than passing complete string i can pass number of lines as well by c# code, but i have tried it but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could do this by using XSLT 2.0 processor easily:**

Try the XSL file with any text file, given as param `textFile`. It would count lines in the file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="textFile">file:/c:/style.css</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Count of line in file&#x20;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$textFile"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text>is&#x20;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$CountOfLines"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="CountOfLines">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(tokenize(unparsed-text(resolve-uri($textFile,base-uri())),'[\r\n]+'))"/>
    </xsl:variable>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am getting error that is base-uri() is unknown

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use an ``.NET XslTransnform`` or ``.NET XslCompileTransnform`` or a similar processor, which would not work.

Comment: yup i am using .NET Transformation ,so now what should i do

Comment: You may try [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE?), for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression to calculate the number of lines in a string `$pText`**:

```
1 + string-length() - string-length(translate($pText, '&#xA;', ''))
```

**Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 transformation that uses this XPath expression:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="pText" select="/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "1 + string-length($pText) - string-length(translate($pText, '&#xA;', ''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<text>aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc</text>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
3
```

**Do note**: You have to read the text file in your C# program and pass its text to the transformation as parameter.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**

Almost the same, but in XSLT 2.0 one can use its standard `unparsed-text()` function to read a text file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="pTextFileName" select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/delete.txt'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vText" select="unparsed-text($pTextFileName)"/>
  "<xsl:value-of select="$vText"/>"
  ===================
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "1 + string-length($vText) - string-length(translate($vText, '&#xA;', ''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on any XML document (not used), and if the file 'c:/temp/delete/delete.txt' contains:**

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
3
```

Comment: +1, Great solution, but, somehow we have manipulate incoming text prior processing through XSL(XSLT v1.0 processor).

Comment: @Cylian: You are welcome. The OP has indicated that he is using XSLT together with C# -- so getting the text and passing it to the transformation isn't a problem. Do notice that the transformation processes whatever is passed to it via the global/external parameter `$pText` .

Comment: You are absolutely right sir!

Comment: thank you  sir for your response but i can not use c# code for this purpose ,if i allowed to use c# then i can directly pass the number of lines in XML rather than complete string. So is there any to read text file from XSLT code

Comment: @user1340912: Yes -- in XSLT 2.0 (using the `unparsed-text()` function). In XSLT 1.0 only text files that contain a well-formed XML document can be read (using the `document()` function). Otherwise this isn't directly possible. If the text file contains a well-formed XML fragment (all `<` and `&` are escaped), then it may be simply surrounded with the tags of a single top element, or, more unobtrusive, a new file can be created that has just this top element and an entity reference inside it that points to the text file. Or, XInclude could be used for the same thing, provided it is supported.

Comment: @user1340912: This could also be possible if you invoke the XSLT 1.0 processor from the command-line and the command-line utility can accept parameters -- I think many modern command languages can read a file and provide its content as an argument to another command.

Comment: thanks for all, can u show me any code example of xlst that contain c# code, i have tried it but it always give an run-time error that "Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called"

Comment: @user1340912: I posted a separate answer that contains the requested example of calling a C# extension function from XSLT.